# How to get Placed Order Information By Customer Id in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer, collection, sales

I have tried this to load

`$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(1100000255);`

but this is solution for to load order information of that particular orderId.

**But i need to know order summary of particular Customer with his or her Customer id.**

Answer (score 1):

to load this order you need to `loadByIncrementId`

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId(1100000255);
```

if you want customer order by customer id then

```
$customer_id = 5;
    $_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer_id);
```

Comment: these will return all order details of customer_id = 5 good  but next i want to get only first order date and last order date of specific customer_id order.

Comment: `$_orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer_id); 
$_orders->setOrder('entity_id','DESC');
$_orders->getFirstItem();` or chnage order to `created_at`

Comment: i have did that  i want only order date like same but different filter i have used and got the actual result which i want. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

***1100000255 is order increment id not order id for system.***

For getting order details by increment id ,You need to use `loadByIncrementId()`

**`$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadbyIncrementId(1100000255);`**

*Note:* `loadByIncrementId()` give single order not multiple Order

*For Getting  Orders of a particular Customer id then*  You should Call Sales order Collection *`Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()`* Then filter that Collection id  by field  `customer_id`

> ```
> $Collection=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
> $Collection->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customerId)
> ```

That collection can be filter by any fields of *sales_flat_order table*,So as per as ,require you can  get *orders collection customer name, Customer email etc.*